# How can I split a timestamp column into date and time in spark

Tags: pyspark

I want to split timestamp value into date and time.

eg:

```
1/20/2016 3:20:30 PM
1/20/2016 3:20:31 PM
1/20/2016 3:20:32 PM
1/20/2016 3:20:32 PM
1/20/2016 3:20:32 PM
1/20/2016 3:20:33 PM
1/20/2016 3:20:34 PM
1/20/2016 3:20:34 PM
```

needs to be split into 1/20/2016  and 3:20:30 PM

using sql spilt function I am unable to process it correctly

```
split_col = pyspark.sql.functions.split(df['ServerTime'], ' ')
df_date = df.withColumn('Date', split_col.getItem(0))
df_time = df.withColumn('Time', split_col.getItem(1))
```

Any help guys????

Comment: What kind of error do you have ?

Answer (score 10):

As the date and time can come in any format, the right way of doing this is to convert the date strings to a Datetype() and them extract Date and Time part from it.

Let take the below sample data

```
server_times = sc.parallelize([('1/20/2016 3:20:30 PM',),
                     ('1/20/2016 3:20:31 PM',),
                     ('1/20/2016 3:20:32 PM',)]).toDF(['ServerTime'])
```

The **Date** and **Time** parts can be extracted as follows any format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, from_unixtime, date_format

df.select(unix_timestamp(df.ServerTime, 'm/d/yyyy h:m:ss a').alias('ut'))\
  .select(from_unixtime('ut').alias('dty'))\
  .select(date_format('dty', 'M/d/yyyy').alias('Date'),
          date_format('dty', 'h:m:s a').alias('Time'))\
  .show()

+---------+----------+
|     Date|      Time|
+---------+----------+
|1/20/2016|3:20:30 PM|
|1/20/2016|3:20:31 PM|
|1/20/2016|3:20:32 PM|
+---------+----------+
```

You can project these two into separate dataframes if you want.

Comment: how can the code be improved to include server time aswell

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pyspark.sql.functions.concat` to concatenate the relevant time bits together again. Let's first create some test data:

```
df = sc.parallelize([('1/20/2016 3:20:30 PM',),
                     ('1/20/2016 3:20:31 PM',),
                     ('1/20/2016 3:20:32 PM',)]).toDF(['ServerTime'])
```

You can do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
split_col = pyspark.sql.functions.split(df['ServerTime'], ' ')
df_date = df.withColumn('Date', split_col.getItem(0))
df_time = df.withColumn('Time', F.concat(split_col.getItem(1),F.lit(' '),split_col.getItem(2)))
```

After running `df_time.show()`, the following output is returned:

```
+--------------------+----------+
|          ServerTime|      Time|
+--------------------+----------+
|1/20/2016 3:20:30 PM|3:20:30 PM|
|1/20/2016 3:20:31 PM|3:20:31 PM|
|1/20/2016 3:20:32 PM|3:20:32 PM|
+--------------------+----------+
```

Running `df_date.show()` returns:

```
+--------------------+---------+
|          ServerTime|     Date|
+--------------------+---------+
|1/20/2016 3:20:30 PM|1/20/2016|
|1/20/2016 3:20:31 PM|1/20/2016|
|1/20/2016 3:20:32 PM|1/20/2016|
+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Won't work for date times like "1/1/2016 3:20:30 PM" or "1/20/2016 11:20:30 PM"